# post and delete method for ios devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

## Adding a playlist to youtube account

```
POST /feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<id>VIDEO_ID</id>
<yt:position>1</yt:position>
</entry>
```

## delete playlist of youtube account

```
DELETE /feeds/api/users/USERNAME/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

HOW DO I SEND THIS BOTH METHOD TO YOUTUBE SERVER IN IOS AND GET RESULT.
ihave all require data (e.g. token and allthat) but idont know how to send this post and delete method to server and get response

Comment: YES i know that but how?

Comment: myreqmutable = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:del]];
        [myreqmutable setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
        [myreqmutable setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [myreqmutable setValue:@"2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
     
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myreqmutable returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Comment: i m doing this but not working

Comment: How is it not working? Do you an error? If so, what is the error? Please describe your problem in detail.

Comment: i can post another answer after 7 hours

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only Google's API in your project you can use GData Objective-C client library

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

They have [extensive documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction) and [examples](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample%253Fstate%253Dclosed)